# REST: Link resources with dependency

Tags: api, rest, resources, relationship

I'm trying to design a relationship between two different resources with dependency. The scenario is:

Two resources, the first one called "account" and the second one called "person".

In my API the "person" resource is a representation of a person in real world, with name, age, gender, address, telephone, etc. Account is the resource responsible to authenticate a person, like a login.

So the representation of "person" resource looks like below:

```
{
    "id": "7828292",
    "name": "Joseph Climber",
    "email": "yourmail@email.com",
    "gender": "M",
    "telephones": {
        "main": {
            "number": "898987777"
        },
        "secondary": {
            "number": "909099090"
        },
        "business": {
            "number": "937363902"
        }
    },
    "address": {
         "rel": "address",
         "href": "person/{ID}/address"
     }
}
```

And the representation of "account" resource looks like:

```
{
    "id": "login@email.com",
    "tokenAccess": "5E69FAE25F4B4F3E8CC5DE09A8163520",
    "link": {
         "rel": "person",
         "href": "person/{id}"
     }
}
```

My problem is: when I create a new person (POST person) I don't have a way to authenticate the new person, in this case is necessary to create a new account to do this, so this seems a little bit confusing for the API consumers, because the API doesn't express this kind of relationship naturally (basic concept of a good API design).

What is the best way to represent this dependency between account and person resource?

Comment: What do you mean by "authenticate the new person"? Are you talking about the API consumer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if someone attempts to `POST` to `/person` without an access token, then return a status code `401 Unauthorized` with a body something like:

```
{
    "@type": "error",
    "description": "You must be authenticated to POST to person. If you do not have an account, then POST to /account to get an access token."
}
```

I imagine that would be intuitive enough for developers using the API.

Comment: Hi theon, thanks for your answer, but I think that in this way the API still confused.
For example, another problem that I have: how can I associate an account to a person (and vice-versa) if the process of create both are different?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you feel is confusing? If I made a call to `/person` that returned the error message `You must first call /account` I wouldn't find that confusing - it is telling me exactly what to do. Is it because the user doesn't know about the dependency upfront before they make the call? If so, maybe you put something in  your API docs. [Swagger](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/) has a free text section for each API call, where you could explain things like this to your users.